# ignore_user_abort и функция date

Tags: php, дата, таймер

День добрый, обнаружил проблему. Мой код делает запись в бд значения функции date("H:i:s");. Сам скрипт имеет тело

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
set_time_limit(0);
while(true)
{
 //Тут запись date("H:i:s")
}
```

Так вот, все время значение date() одно и тоже, объясните как это исправить?. Я даже сделал по другому. Ради теста file_get_contents() файла с датой, но результат тот же... хотя сам файл, содержимое которого я парсил, выводит все нормально. Прошу помогите!

Comment: А "всё время" - это сколько? Вот немного измененный ваш код, только с задержкой в секунду: http://prntscr.com/bcyi4r.

Comment: Странно, просто вот в чем беда, когда я останавливаю скрипт и запускаю заного - все нормально, но после он начинает использовать старое время

Comment: Я немного не понимаю, зачем вам столько одинаковых записей времени. Учитывая скорости компьютеров, за секунду у вас будет несколько тысяч одинаковых времен, в следующую секунду пойдут новые. Может, есть смысл попробовать с задержкой скрипт?

Comment: нет, ну я образно отписал. Естественно есть и другой код, но проблема именно в том, что этот код работает по таймингу записанным в бд, а тайминг неправильно записывается ибо используется все время одно и тоже время

Comment: Так все-таки если вставите задержку, то, может, это поможет?
Я к тому, что, может, вы просто не заметили, что время все-таки изменилось? У меня ваш код выдает около 5 тысяч одинаковых записей, именно столько успевает за секунду, потом наступает следующая секунда. Вот пример: http://prntscr.com/bcypn5. У вас мои примеры тоже не работают?